# C++. Простая задача

Tags: c++

Задача:
Составить алгоритм увеличения всех трех, введённых с клавиатуры, переменных на 5,если среди них есть хотя бы две равные. В противном случае выдать ответ «равных нет».

Проблема:
При вводе не равных чисел не срабатывает блок if(!equalnumshere)

P.S: Я знаю решение этой задачки без использование массивов, но я поставил себе цель решить эту задачу с использованием массива.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    const int SIZE = 3;
    int arr[SIZE];
    bool equalnumshere = false;

    cout << "Введите первое число:";
    cin >> arr[0];
    cout << "Введите второе число:";
    cin >> arr[1];
    cout << "Введите третье число:";
    cin >> arr[2];

    for (int i = 1; i <= SIZE - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= SIZE - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] == arr[i]) {
                equalnumshere = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!equalnumshere) {
        cout << "Нет равных чисел!";
    }
    else if (equalnumshere) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i <= SIZE - 1) {
            cout << arr[i] + 5 << std::endl;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я новичок в c++. Не судите строго!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очевидно, что у вас сравнивается и число само с собой, а это всегда истинно :)

Попробуйте так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < SIZE ; j++) {
        if (arr[j] == arr[i]) {
            equalnumshere = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Чувак, там же написано int i = 1

Comment: Но почему то когда я переписал твой код, все заработало. Магия

Comment: Сейчас приму ваш вопрос! Спасибо